# How do i split user inputed text into individual characters?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to give the user the ability to drag each individual character they inputed around the screen.

I am not quite sure how to gain access to the individual characters the user inputs.

In my example below i am able to manipulate each character of "placemark". How do i do this for user inputed text?

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>My project</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="character">P</div>
    <div class="character">l</div>
    <div class="character">a</div>
    <div class="character">c</div>
    <div class="character">e</div>
    <div class="character">m</div>
    <div class="character">a</div>
    <div class="character">r</div>
    <div class="character">k</div>

    <br><br>

    <form action="demo_form">
      Word: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.character {
  width: 10px; height: 15px;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: inline;
}
```

Jquery

```
$( init );

function init() {
  $('.character').draggable();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this would work. Just type something in the box and click the button to test it

Basically, the way we do this is:

1. Get the users input and spilt it into an array of characters
2. Join the array in such a way that it wraps each character in an element (span div ... whatever)
3. Add those elements to the DOM
4. Call `.draggable()` on the added elemets

```js
function initDragable($elements) {
  $elements.draggable();
}
initDragable($('.character'));

$(function(){
    $('#make-word').click(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var letters = $('#my-word').val().split('');
      letters = '<div class="character">'+letters.join('</div><div class="character">')+'</div>';
      initDragable($('#word-container').html(letters).find('.character'));
    });
});
```

```css
.character {
  width: 10px;
  height: 15px;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: inline;
  cursor: drag;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="word-container">
  <div class="character">P</div>
  <div class="character">l</div>
  <div class="character">a</div>
  <div class="character">c</div>
  <div class="character">e</div>
  <div class="character">m</div>
  <div class="character">a</div>
  <div class="character">r</div>
  <div class="character">k</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<form action="demo_form">
  Word:
  <input type="text" id="my-word" name="fname">
  <br>
  <button type="button" id="make-word">Make word</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was after, thank you very much.

Comment: Copied exactly what you have done, when i click button, nothing happens? double checked many times

Comment: @Kōdonomusō-ka Make sure you put the click handler inside an *on dom ready function* like `$(function(){  // code in here });`  that way the handler is applied after the element has been added to the page. Because of where SO puts the code, it is not necessary here but it will be if you put it somewhere else in your project. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do it, inputs are not giving you a power to treat each character separately (unless you hack using `.keypress()` trigger via jQuery).

I would recommend using `<button>` which would create a draggable element: `<div class="character">` each time.

OR

The example below shows how to grab last character you typed and converts it into draggable element:

```
$('input[type="text"]').keypress(function() {
    var lastCharacter = $(this).val().slice(-1);
    $('body').append('<div class="draggable">'+lastCharacter +'</div>');
    //make element draggable
    $('.draggable').draggable();
});
```

Comment: Any way to get this lastCharacter method to display its results in a line, rather then underneath?